# High CPU utilization from a script

Tags: linux, bash, redhat, shell-scripting

I found this script is running in my system without any knowledge.

```
#!/bin/sh
if test -r /tmp/.txl/bash.pid; then
pid=$(cat /tmp/.txl/bash.pid)
if $(kill -CHLD $pid >/dev/null 2>&1)
then
sleep 1
else
cd /tmp/.txl
./run &>/dev/null
exit 0
fi
fi
```

Also this script is being triggered by `/tmp/.txl/upd >/dev/null 2>&1`

Can anyone explain why this script is running

Any help will be appreciated..!

Comment: That script is little more then a wrapper around the "./run" script or program. We would need to know what that script is doing to advise.

Comment: If you don't know why the script exists on the system, it means that it was installed by exploiting a vulnerability on your server. You need to restore the server from clean backups and make sure all your software is updated.